# Cardinality of a relation

Tags: set-theory, relations

Let $R:A\to B$  a relation. For each $a \in A$ define $R(a)=\left\lbrace x\in A:aRx \right\rbrace$. Prove that, if $A$ and $B$ are finite sets, then: $$Car(R)=\sum_{a\in A} Car(R(a)).$$

Until now, I suppose $Car(A)=n$ and $Car(B)=m$ for some integers $n,m$, so $Car(R)=nm$, that is why I think it must be proven that $$\sum_{a\in A} Car(R(a)) = nm.$$ But I don't know how to proceed. I really appreciate some hints.

Comment: $Car(A\times B)=mn$.  Why would you conclude $Car(R)=mn$?

Comment: Also I think you mean $R(a)=\{x\in B:aRx\}$.

Comment: Hint1:  $R(a)$ is bijective to $\{a\}\times R(a)$.  Hint2  The sets $\{a_1\}\times R(a_1)$ and $\{a_2\}\times R(a_2)$ are disjoint when $a_1\neq a_2$.  Hint3  What is the union of all of these sets?  Hint 4 What do you know about the Cardinality of a disjoint union?

Comment: @MW I conclude that, because I "link" every element of $A$ with $m$-elements of B. Or that is true only if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint?

Comment: You cannot link an element of $A$ with all elements of $B$.  You can only link $a$ with $b$ when $aRb$ is true.  (It has nothing to do with whether or not $A$ and $B$ are disjoint)